# On Load Js Tree open last level child node

Tags: jquery, jstree

I try to display checked node from database. If tree is already open then it display last level child checked but if tree is not open then it not displaying checked child. My code is as below.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/index.php/supplierProfileManagement/jsTreePreCheck",
     data: {},
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       //$("#tree").jstree('open_all');
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
     //alert(item);
     $("#tree").jstree("open_node", $('#'+item));
     $.jstree.reference('#tree').check_node('#'+item);     
     
    })
    //$("#tree").jstree("refresh");
     }
 });
  
   
}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set for editable tree follow:

```
var _tree = $("#your tree element id").jstree(true); //set editable
var $node = _tree.get_node(item.id); //id of node
_tree.open_node($node);
```